# complex pandas manipulation with isin

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Counterparty':['Bank','Client','Bank','Bank'],
             'Amount':[100, 100, 100, 100]
            })
```

I want to have a flexible selection that uses a string to filter out certain records. Something like:

```
condition ="'Bank'"
result = "df1['Counterparty'].isin(["+condition+"])"
print(eval(result))
```

I am struggling how to select all records that are **NOT** with Counterparty =Bank . ie

```
condition ="Not("Bank"))"
```

Any suggestions how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the unary operation Not (~) as follows

```
condition ="'Bank'"
result = "df1[~df1['Counterparty'].isin(["+condition+"])]"
print(eval(result))
```

the output will be:

```
   Amount Counterparty
1     100       Client
```

### ## EDIT

```
condition ="NOT(Bank)"
def func(c):
     if c.startswith("NOT("):
         return df1[~df1['Counterparty'].isin([c[4:-1]])]
     else:    
         return df1[df1['Counterparty'].isin([c])]
result  = "func(condition)"
print(eval(result))
condition = "Bank"
print(eval(result))

   Amount Counterparty
1     100       Client

   Amount Counterparty
0     100         Bank
2     100         Bank
3     100         Bank
```

Comment: I want the result to be flexible. ie. the result should depend only on the condition. If I pass a Not condition , the result should reflect this. Similarly, If I just pass the condition Bank, it should only show me records with a counterparty of Bank

Comment: There is no direct way to do so, however. I've edited my post with a suggestion that's hack-y but would work

Comment: the if condition seems to be the only way to get around the problem ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

First using [eval is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/2901002).

What about use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental)?

```
condition ="Bank"
result = df1.query('Counterparty not in @condition')
print (result)
   Amount Counterparty
1     100       Client
```

Comment: I want the "not" to be part of "condition". In this way I can flexibly change the filter criteria without having to change code

Comment: I think it is problem. Because `condition` variable is not condition, but filtered string. So `condition ="Not("Bank"))"` cannot be used.

Comment: because condition is all string `"df1['Counterparty'].isin(["+condition+"])"`

Comment: df.query uses df.eval under the hood, see the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6b27de318619ab7524e24976c31adf20e59c25f5/pandas/core/frame.py#L4479-L4498)

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has string operations that can be accessed by using "str".

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Counterparty':['Bank','Client','Bank','Bank'],
             'Amount':[100, 100, 100, 100]
            })
```

to find bank you can do this.

```
df1.Counterparty.str.match('Bank')
```

if you want to find anything but, add a tilde:

```
~df1.Counterparty.str.match('Bank')
```

Finally, if you want the data then just put this boolean query in

```
df1[~df1.Counterparty.str.match('Bank')]
```

A few other notes.  Don't try to build expressions that need to be evaluated (just forget eval is there for a while)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `eval` in this way, it poses a security risk.

There are at least 2 viable options:

1. Use `df.query`, [as explained by @jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48850357/9209546).
2. Use a 3rd party library like [`pandasql`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandasql), which will let you apply SQL-like queries, e.g. `pysqldf("SELECT * FROM df WHERE Counterparty <> 'bank';")`